# Get most popular videos of a channel by its name

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to list most popular (or newest) videos of a channel by its name using YouTube 3.0 API.

I already implemented this, just not sure if it is correct way to do this, so need an advice.

First of I find channel ID by name (e.g. TEDxTalks in place of `{channel_name}`):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&q={channel_name}&key={API_KEY}
```

Then I get videos of this channel ID, ordered by `viewCount` (or `date`), which perfectly lists videos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channel_id}&order=viewCount&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

How reliable is the first request? If name is the exact match of channel url slug or username (e.g. tedxtalks), will it always return corresponding channel? Or is there any more reliable way to get channel ID by its name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search API is not for exact match query. And it searching for all channel title(username found in URL if exist), channel name(xxx added 1 video) and even channel ID!

To answer your question, unfortunately it's not reliable and no other more reliable way.

A quick example, try to query username "abc".

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=abc&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The Search API response will return ABCNetwork, ABCNews, udruzenjeabc... and so on. No channelTitle(username) "abc" in the first 50 items.

Even though not all channels have username. If you got username of specific channel, then you should use Channel API for exact match query,

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=abc&maxResults=5&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

You might wonder why YouTube API doesn't provide exact search for "channel name"(xxx added 1 video)? It's because channel name is not unique, as a person name is not unique.

As indicated at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids:

> If you are using v3 and want to retrieve the channel ID that
>   corresponds to the currently authorized user, you can call the
>   channels.list(part="id", mine=true) method. This is equivalent to
>   asking for the channel profile of the default user in v2.
>
> If you ever do find yourself with an arbitrary legacy YouTube username
>   that you need to translate into a channel ID using v3 of the API, you
>   can make a channels.list(part="id", forUsername="username") call to
>   the API.
>
> If you only know a display name and are looking to find the
>   corresponding channel, the search.list(part="snippet", type="channel",
>   q="display name") method will come in handy. You should be prepared to
>   deal with the possibility of the call returning more than one item in
>   the response, since display names are not unique.

Finally, i have no idea why YouTube didn't force to generate a unique readable username (like how Facebook add a random number at the end of duplicated username, e.g. zuck.5 and zuck.21 ) for all new user.

References:

1. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
2. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it
3. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?hl=en
4. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

Comment: Got it, I can rely only on channel ID. Thank you very much for such a full reply. 

As asking user to enter channel ID is not very user-friendly. I'll probably use `search?type=channel?q={name}` just to list all channels, and ask user to select the one that he wants.